# SSMS runs very slowly if even a medium number of rows are returned in Results Pane

Tags: ssms

I'm using SSMS 2017 and have an issue that means as soon as I have even a small number of rows (10,000)the user experience lows down. I do have Redgate SQL tools installed, but colleagues have the same setup and do not see the issue.

If I have a large number of rows, 100K plus then the system is unusable and sometimes even hangs or crashes.

Has anyone else had this issue and more importantly have any suggested fixes. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app and also checked memory usage which is low. The data is not that large really, just SSMS has a bit of a hissy fit.
[1 row of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UCwi.png)
Any thoughts appreciated.

regards,
Anthony

Comment: I would start with a plane base install of ssms, and see if that works.  record count isn't really a good indicator of data size either, 10k records can be a few mb, or potential several GB.   Even 10K records is an awfully big result set to be working with,   If you're extracting data, I would use the build in export tool before I tried to query the data,

Comment: Thanks Patrick - I realise this is the case, which is why I provided an image of 1 row. My issue is I have a problem and my colleagues don't with the same data. I have done a clean install of SSMS 2018RC and it performs in the same way. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Are you and your colleagues running the same or at least similar hardware? Does ssms hang up, or your entire machine?

Comment: Yes, we have similar hardware. SSMS does not usually hang, it just takes a long time between actions. (e.g selecting a new location in the query text, wait 15 seconds, type something in wait 15 seconds, move cursor wait 15 seconds, hide result pane, wait 15 seconds and then SSMS response goes back to normal until the results pane is displayed again...